# Conditionally changing variables that match multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to clean a survey data set and am having trouble with conditionals. Thanks to all who answered my last question, but this one is slightly different and stumping me too.

I have a dataset like the one below. I am trying to write a statement such that:

- If X, Y, and Z are all #NULL!, it changes those #NULL! entries to NA. Variable a is there to represent the 90+ other variables that are in the set that I don't want to mess with.
- If any X, Y, or Z have numbers in them, #NULL changes to 0.

Here is an example dataset that I built that shows what I mean:

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(
  X = as.factor(sample(c("1.00", "#NULL!"), 10, replace = TRUE)),
  Y = as.factor(sample(c("2.00", "#NULL!"), 10, replace = TRUE)),
  Z = as.factor(sample(c("3.00", "#NULL!"), 10, replace = TRUE)),
  a = as.factor(sample(c("4.00", "#NULL!"), 10, replace = TRUE))
)
df
```

Output:

`> df
        X      Y      Z      a
1    1.00   2.00 #NULL!   4.00
2    1.00   2.00   3.00 #NULL!
3  #NULL! #NULL! #NULL!   4.00
4  #NULL!   2.00   3.00   4.00
5    1.00 #NULL!   3.00 #NULL!
6  #NULL!   2.00   3.00 #NULL!
7  #NULL! #NULL!   3.00 #NULL!
8  #NULL! #NULL!   3.00   4.00
9  #NULL!   2.00 #NULL! #NULL!
10   1.00 #NULL!   3.00   4.00`

In this case, all null values for X, Y, and Z should be made 0 except for row 3, where they should be made NA. Column a should remain untouched. Does anybody have an idea how to approach this? Several convoluted `ifelse()` statements haven't worked, and I've been trying to modify a `dplyr` script someone suggested for another problem but I can't get that to work either.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to return as `factor` column or `numeric`

Comment: What's the logic about row 3? For any row with all NULL, replace values with `NA`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response - I need these returned as factors, and yes, all NULL -> NA. XYZ are all race variables, so it's possible to have one or more, but a single NA should just be a 0, as they answered the question and just aren't X. If they're all NULL, it's as if they didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

As the columns are `factor`, create a `level` '0' and change the level "#NULL!" to "0" and replace the rows that have all 0's to NA

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {levels(x) <- c(levels(x), "0")
           levels(x)[levels(x) == "#NULL!"] <- "0"
        x})

df[rowSums(df == '0') == ncol(df), ] <- NA
```

---

Assuming that the OP wanted to return as `numeric` column

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) 
      as.numeric(replace(as.character(x), x== "#NULL!", "0")))    
df[rowSums(df == 0) == ncol(df), ] <- NA
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on how to read this because I'm not familiar with the `lapply` function (looking into it!) - is the 'x' here supposed to be my variables 'X,' 'Y,' and 'Z'? Because if so, I'm getting an error message that says `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, rowSums(testdata == "0") == ncol(testdata),  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames` and I don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: @anongard  I am using your example and couldn't get an error

Comment: Ah! I don't know what I did wrong before, but I tried it again and it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: So actually, the first part works. It's the second part, the df[rowSums] bit, that is throwing that error. I should say that I have much more than 3 columns in my dataset - could that be the issue? I'm playing with the syntax to see if I can specify the rows for which ==0 should result in NA. Do you know a solution off the top of your head?

Comment: @anongard  Do you have all the columns as `factor` in your dataset?  What is the output you are getting for `df == "0"` and `rowSums(df == "0")`  If the original dataset is similar as the example with `n` columns, it should work.  It is better to show dput of example that mimics your original data so that we know the structure

Answer (score 1):

This is a roundabout way to do it, but converting your factors to numeric first makes it easier to get the result.

```
new.df<-df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%               #convert columns to characters first
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric) %>%              #convert the characters to numeric
  mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, replace = 0) %>%   #replace all NAs with 0
  mutate(TEST = ifelse(X==0&Y==0&Z==0, NA, 0)) %>%     #create column to test for conditions
  mutate(X = ifelse(is.na(TEST), "#NULL!", X),
         Y = ifelse(is.na(TEST), "#NULL!", Y),
         Z = ifelse(is.na(TEST), "#NULL!", Z)) %>%     #replace NAs with initial NULL results
  select(-TEST)                                        #remove test column
```

Comment: This works! I don't know how I missed this response earlier. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm. Actually, something in this is changing all of the #NULL! in the rest of my dataset to 0, which I do not want. I will play around with this more...